# how to resize an image while maintaining width and height ratio

Tags: php, image, height, width

I am using this function to resize an uploaded image:

```
function imageResize($imageResourceId,$width,$height) {

    $targetWidth =750;
    $targetHeight =300;

    $targetLayer = imagecreatetruecolor($targetWidth,$targetHeight);
    imagecopyresampled($targetLayer,$imageResourceId,0,0,0,0,$targetWidth,$targetHeight, $width,$height);

    return $targetLayer;
}
```

But this makes the image 750 width and 300 height. The height should be flexible and depends on the width.
So i am looking for something like this:

```
 $targetWidth = 750;
 $targetHeight = auto;
```

i really do not know how i should do this...

Comment: Calculate the ratio and multiply with height. `$targetHeight = $targetWidth/$width * $height;`. I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Now it works great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily calculate the ratio of the original image and apply it to the resized one:

```
$targetHeight = ($height / $width) * $targetWidth
```